# MVC Razor - What is standard practice to make this html.Partial dynamic

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

In a default MVC VS2017 project I've created, I've added a new `View` folder with an `Index` partial view. So the structure during html render goes:

```
_Layout -> Blog(Index) -> Blog(pageNumber)
```

Inside the Blog Index (partial view enveloped by _Layout) I want to then `render` a specific "Blog page":

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = asp_net_mvc_site.Resources.Common.LinkBlog;
}
<div class="jumbotron"><h1>THE BLOG</h1></div>

<div class="container body-content">
    @Html.Partial("Blog1")
</div>
```

So this works fine, but I want to have the user click on a "Blog page number" somewhere on-site and then pass this in to my `@Html.Partial("Blog" + x)` line, where x is the page number. I believe I could have a global variable that stores `currentBlogPageNumber` x but feel that this probably isn't good practice?

I decided to add a View ActionResult in my BlogController with the page number passed to it but then I've no idea how to marry this action with the `@Html.Partial()` on the cshtml page.

I've got a BlogController to which I've added:

```
    public ActionResult View(int pageNumber)
    {
        return View("~/Views/Home/Blog/Blog" + pageNumber + ".cshtml");
    }
```

P.S I'm still new to working with MVC and MVVM architechture so go easy?!

Comment: how many blog numbers you have and you have view for each one?

Comment: what about a view-model object ? return View("~/Views/Home/Blog/Blog.cshtml", pageNumber); and then partial can access to the pageNumber like @Model

Comment: I'll probably get up to about 20 before consolidating, and will have a "partial" view for each one yes.

Comment: Thanks Jordi, I don't know immediately how to set this up but will try and flesh out your suggestion.